# Sending data from Intel Galileo to phone

Tags: android, iphone, arduino, wireless, intel-galileo

I am trying to gauge the feasibility/work load required for a project and have limited previous experience with wireless communications. What sort of back-end/hardware is required to send data from a small home device to a mobile phone (not within wireless range of the device)? similar to https://www.kickstarter.com/projects/505428730/blink-wire-free-hd-home-monitoring-and-alert-syste

Ideally I want to send data from an Intel Galileo to a phone with the minimum number of in between steps. How would I achieve this?

Comment: Link is dead it seems.

Comment: fixed it, for some reason they misspelt system in the actual URL

Answer (score 0):

One thing to bear in mind as you begin to flesh out your concept is -- do not allow your desire to 'get something running' to trump your goals. Having had a cursory glimpse of your Kickstarter page -- I assume that your final system will be secure.

Having said that, HTTP is a great place to start. RESTful services, for all the jargon that wraps the concept, are nothing more than HTTP GETs, as are most services -- the URL itself contains the specifics and you can even write server code to turn a GET into an action on the server.

On the Galileo side, in my opinion -- the node.js library is great for this type of thing. I have a rudimentary HTTP server running at home, right now. It only serves a static page, but...by parsing the path sent by the browser, I can easily create a RESTful service.

The 'trick' is getting your Galileo exposed to the Internet in such a way that it works like a proper HTTP server.

I used a domain that I own to create a subdomain and configured my router to send the HTTP requests to the Galileo's private (WLAN) IP. I use the wired Ethernet for SSH to the Intel XDK development system.

This weekend, I will write the process up and you can get the gist of how to do the same from that -- it isn't particularly onerous, but -- there are a few things that must be setup properly to create this sandbox you are asking about.

[My Galileo Gen 2 (It is 100% 'stock')](http://stations.jinzai-studio.net/index.html)